# Software to Convert Various File Formats to TIFF-F for Internet Faxing

Tags: linux, fax

Does anyone know of software that can run on a Linux (CentOS) web server that will take user uploaded material, convert it to TIFF-F and either return the converted TIFF-F file to the user or e-mail it as an attachment? It can be written in PHP, JAVA, RoR or Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend installing [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) -- it's probably available through your package manager of choice. It comes with a myriad of command-line tools to process images. The one you want is [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), which can be used to transform images (or any of it's other [supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)) via

`convert $INPUT_IMAGE -monochrome -compress fax $OUTPUT_TIF`

You can then take the output file and email it with [any of the methods described in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/17589/easiest-way-to-email-file-via-command-line-in-nix).

Comment: ImageMagick is the swiss army knife of image manipulation.

Comment: +1 convert is all you ever need for image conversion. :)