# Sending email from a script including attachments

Tags: email, scripting, shell, attachment

I want to email a html file and some images to someone from a script. The standard answer seems to be to use `mutt`. However I don't have that installed at the moment.

- Is there another way I could do it?
- Is there any security vulnerbilities with installing mutt?
- I don't need a full on mail reader, I just wanna send some attachments, is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail`, [`mailx`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailx) and it's derivatives are the most commonly used MUAs for such jobs.

You'll find them much leaner to install and maintain than `mutt`.

It's important to note that some of the derivatives don't make sending attachments as easy as others.

Comment: How do I send attachments?

Comment: "man mailx" has all the answers.

Comment: man uuencode will also help

Comment: It depends on the specific version you have. You might be interested in this thread though - http://serverfault.com/questions/17589/easiest-way-to-email-file-via-command-line-in-nix

Answer (score 2):

To send attachments using mailx:

```
(uuencode file1.png file1.png
 uuencode file2.html file2.html
 echo "this is in the message body") | mailx -s "This is the Subject" kyle@kylerocks.com
```

uuencode is included the the sharutils package.

Comment: Technically they aren't attachments </pedant>

Comment: Why not? (Not trying to be argumentative) even you are being pedantic, I don't know the difference, and I don't like not knowing :-)

Comment: The it'd be a pleasure to explain :) If you take a look at the source of an email produced by the above then you'll see that the body contains the raw uuencode's without any boundaries. Most MUAs will interpret these uuencoded content as attached files, but some will not and truly they aren't. Real attachements are sent as part of a MIME multipart message which defines the bounaries and types for each part.